# implementing ajax using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json

i'm tried to implement ajax using jQuery.Its my first time to use ajax.so in a button click i need to display the current datetime. For this, i write the below code

//==============aspx page===============

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function (){
        var Button1 = $("#Button1");
        var Label1 = $("#Label1");
        Button1.click(function (){
          $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/myownajax14/WebService/WebService1.asmx/GetDateTime",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    $("#Label1").text(msg.d);
                    //alert('hi');
                    },
                error:alert('error');     
            });     

        });
    });
```

//================asmx.cs page===========

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetDateTime()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

My problem is,it doesn't give the answer..and it doesn't show any error.Have any mistake in this code?Please help me..

Comment: First you should trace your Request using FireBug

Comment: You can debug this to see exactly where the problem is. For example, while debugging through VS, put a breakpoint in the method and see if it hits. If so, then the javascript to call it is ok, so the problem must be after. Also, look at the Network tab in your browser's developer tools to see if a server request ever actually happens. If not, then the problem is with the code that calls the method. Whatever the result, you'll learn a lot about what the problem is (or isn't) by debugging using your tools.

Comment: try this: `Button1.click(function (e){ e.preventDefault()` and use error function `error:function(){alert('error')};   `

Comment: @Jai : i tried it.but its not worked.still gave the same result..

Comment: @pearl90 try this in success function and look in the console what do you get there: `console.log(msg);`

Comment: @Jai: it shows 'msg is undefined'

Comment: can you give a try like this in your web method : `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now.ToString());
`

Comment: @Karthik:when i tried it,an error occured.ie, the name 'JsonConvert' does not exist in the current context.Did i need to add any reference?

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar problem it's simple try this:

You need to specify `type="button"` attribute.

Comment: Here is the same problem what I have experienced http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567951/simple-ajax-call-not-working-with-button-click

Comment: Have you gone through my question posted?

Answer (score 0):

contentType: "application/json;" means that the client need the server to response a json type data.But the server response a string type one instead.

In the "success" block,the "msg" must be like '2010-10-10',so error happens in msg.d.

try the following for a string type data,or response a json type data in the server code such as {"y":2010,"m":10,"d":10}.

```
contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
success: function (date) {
    $("#Label1").text(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing the ASMX directly using a browser? This way, you can easily see what kind of response your ASMX is producing...